# Ranking methods for [1-X] voters and N candidates

Tags: decision-theory

### Situation

I must rank N options (`N = 54` here, but could be lower or higher) according to X voters (`X = 1` here, though I am also interested on the `X = 2` case, as well as a more general case).

### Goal

Assuming the voters can spend any "reasonable" amount of time to cast their vote (up to a couple hours), what are the ways to obtain a full ranking of options/to compute a score for each options? Additionally, which are those that can also be applied for more voters?
I understand that the case `X = 1` can be weird, as a single individual could be assumed to know their preferences, but with potentially dozens or hundreds of options, it is not always easy determining the best one, let alone the full ranking.
One of the ways to cast the vote could then be to do pairwise comparisons and score the options from there.

### Current leads

This situation reminded me of the [Condorcet Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method#Summary), though I am not sure of its necessity in the `X = 1` case.
Is this the best option anyway? And what about the more general case?
Additionally, if this problem is not related to decision theory but another concept, do not hesitate to tell me, I'll try and correct the question/the tags.

Thanks a lot!

### Edit

To clarify:

1. In the case `X = 1`, the pairwise comparison can indeed rank all options without much difficulty, and the process can be optimized to limit the number of comparison needed. But is it the only method to get an "ideal" ranking? I think so, but am wandering if I am missing something here.
2. In the more general cases of `X > 1`, it seems to me that the pairwise comparisons could only take us so far, but that we need another system to determine which option is "the best". In particular, pairwise comparisons can give us the rankings for each voter, but combining the rankings could be tricky. As far as I can understand it, it seems like a ranking combination issue (which seems like what [@lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu)'s comment pointed to). Does the evoked standard voting schemes methods relate to Borda/Plurality/etc.? If not, which are they? In order for me to properly research them and their advantages/drawbacks.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "$[1-X]$ voters " mean?  Why would it be a challenge to sort the votes of a single voter?  What difference does it make how long it takes?  I think you must have some critical context in mind that you left off.

Comment: You may be aware of the standard voting schemes, and of the fact that there is no "perfect" voting scheme.  Why not use the standard methods?  Are you changing the assumptions or the goals in some way that changes the usual conclusions?

Comment: Can you edit your post for clarity?  As it stands, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I assume that there might be differences between 1 voter and X voters, particularly in terms of scoring the candidates/options. The difference regarding the time is due to the following application of the theory. For instance, there might be a perfect scoring system satisfying my criteria but taking an infinite amount of iteration, this would then be unusable in my case, though theoretically perfect (or the most near-perfect).

Comment: Not following.  Obviously there are differences between single voters and multiple voters.  At least under usual assumptions, each voter knows (or can determine) their votes, but reaching a consensus might be difficult.  And, obviously, if it takes infinitely long for a single voter to evaluate the options then you can't proceed.

Comment: This is all very vague.  These problems critically come down assumptions and goals, but you haven't said what you are assuming nor what the goal is. "best" is subjective.  What are you trying to optimize? I suggest looking up the standard methods and the theorems about those.  If you are modifying the assumptions  or the goals that are used in those references, then it is critical to say exactly how you are modifying them.

Comment: "At least under usual assumptions, each voter knows (or can determine) their votes". This can be a strong assumption for me here, at least within reasonable time. The multiplication of options render the ranking difficult without a scoring technique. Additionally, as there is no way to objectively score the options, they can simply be compared and evaluated in relation to the others. The quantity I want to optimize (to maximize, really) is $\sum_{i=0}^{N-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N-1}(score(option_i) - score(option_j))$

Comment: Once again, this is all very vague.  If you want to include time as a variable you have to explain how it figures in...that is, how do you balance "getting the closest to a clear winner" versus "efficiency".  And "score" is not defined.  Again I suggest:  this is all heavily discussed in the literature.  Look up the standard methods, they have good points and they have bad points.  If you are designing a voting scheme, you need to weigh the good and bad points and make choices.  Arrow's Theorem really assures us that there can be no perfect solution, so it's a question of compromise.

Comment: I understand this is vague, though I am also trying to figure it out more precisely myself. When you refer to "the literature", do you have any example of resources that could prove useful to me here?   
Here, I am not defining a clear upper time limit, but there are $N!$ possible rankings to evaluate, while only $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ pairwise comparisons, thus making it easier and shorter to do the comparisons when there are many options.

Comment: Also, I purposefully didn't define the scoring method because this was one thing to discuss here (the scoring should only depend on the result of the comparisons, not on the nature of the options, this is to the voter to evaluate)

Comment: Look up the terms you have used, Condorcet is a standard method.  It has good and bad points, as does every method.  Ranked sorting, or Borda methods, are also popular.  Study the statement and proof of Arrow's Impossibility Theorem.  Again, it's fine to modify these and it's fine to introduce new assumptions and goals, but these have got to be clear and explicit and, in all cases, the old methods should be compared in light of the new requirements.